# Non repeating binary pairs of n values

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, classification, regression

I am working with cart algorithm and i have the following problem,i need to try all possible splits of n values in order to determine the best.So lets say i have 3 values("low","medium",high) then the possible splits(pairs) would be:(assuming **low=0**,**medium=1**,**high=2**)

- 0,1-2 low,medium-high
- 1,0-2 medium,low-high
- 2,1-0 high,medium-low

For 4 values(a,b,c,d) it would be:

- ab,cd
- ac,bd
- ad,bc
- abc,d
- adb,c
- adc,b
- bcd,a

Problem is i dont know n so the solution must be recursive. The possible splits are **2<sup>n-1</sup>-1**. I am really stuck and most of the code is complete for cart and i really don't want to restrict it to binary values.

Comment: Seems like the number of possibilities are `n!` - aren't you looking for a permutation - each 'value' needs to appear exactly once - or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It should be non repeating low,medium-high is the same with low,high-medium sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Still not following, what are all the possible combinations with 4 values?

Comment: if I totally understood the problem; You are wanting to seperate the n elements into 2 groups, their order in the group doesn't matter. So possibilities for 4 elements are :

 {O}  , {1, 2, 3} &
 {1}  , {0, 2, 3} &
 {2}  , {0, 1, 3} &
 {3}  , {0, 1, 2} &
 {0, 1}  , {2, 3} &
 {0, 2}  , {1, 3} &
 {0, 3}  , {1, 2} 
My question is how do you know the best pair of groups ? is there any evaluation function ?

Comment: Yes i use gini index,i dont know how to generate the pairs though using a recursive way.

Comment: "i really don't want to restrict it to binary values" I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Please explain.

Comment: I mean that i dont want to have only two values for example a and b so that it would be easy to implement.I want to be able to have n values.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So does the input set only contain unique values {a,b,c,d} or can the input set have repeated values like {a,a,a,b,b,c,d}

Comment: I think the question could benefit from some heavy editing to make it a good stand-alone question. "The cart algorithm" is irrelevant and unexplained, and the tags "tree", "classification", "c" and "regression" are also irrelevant. Same for "binary values" and the commentary about the question-asker's state of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming that all the items in the input set are unique...*

You hinted at the answer to your own question when you stated that the possible splits are 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1.  That is correct.  For example with four items there are 2<sup>3</sup>-1 = 7 splits.

If you consider all of the possible values of a 4-bit binary number, you can see how to easily find all of the possible splits.

```
ABCD
0000   ignore (not a split if all items in same group)
0001   ABC,D
0010   ABD,C
0011   AB,CD
0100   ACD,B
0101   AC,BD
0110   AD,BC
0111   A,BCD
1000   ignore (same as 0111)
1001   ignore (same as 0110)
1010   ignore (same as 0101)
1011   ignore (same as 0100)
1100   ignore (same as 0011)
1101   ignore (same as 0010)
1110   ignore (same as 0001)
1111   ignore (not a split if all items in same group)
```

So the algorithm is increment a variable `count` from 1 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1, and for each `count` separate the items into groups based on whether the corresponding bit in `count` is 0 or 1.

Comment: Amazing answer,so simple yet i would have never thought that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A split is a subset of your set and its complement.

Since you want to treat the split A-B and B-A as the same, you can always put the first value in your input set on the left. We also need to be careful not to include a split where one side has no elements (eg: "abcd-"),

Putting this together in Python:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(s):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def splits(s):
    ss = set(s[1:])
    for p in powerset(s[1:]):
        if not p: continue
        cmpl = ss.difference(p)
        yield ''.join([s[0]] + sorted(cmpl)), ''.join(p)

print list(splits('abcd'))
print list(splits('012'))
```

Comment: I dont know python,i 've tried and online compiler and it didnt compile. Thanks though...